# jquery datepicker icon inside input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Has anyone tried or know of a way to place the calendar icon inside of the input field aligned to the right?  I know how to implement it normally but have no clue how to place in the input field.

Comment: you could apply a background image to the text input...

Comment: I thought about that....was thinking they need to click the icon.  But I guess they can click anywhere in the field and that's good enough....

Comment: Yep, anywhere in the field will initialise the datepicker. If not there already, put `cursor: pointer` on the input and you wouldn't notice the difference